# invert singular matrix on python

Tags: python, scipy

I have to read multiple data from `csv` files, and when I want to invert matrix from `csv` data, I get this:

```
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

and the process get stuck on this section :

```
J = np.mat([dtdx,dtdy,dtdz]).transpose()
dd = np.mat(ttcal-tt)
dm = (scipy.linalg.inv(J.transpose()*J))*((J.transpose())*(dd.transpose()))
```

and data from "J" like this :

```
[[-6.81477651e-03 -7.90320450e-03  6.50533437e-05]
 [-6.71080644e-03 -6.00135428e-03  6.50533437e-05]]
```

and data from "dd" like this :

```
[[0.00621772 0.00537531]]
```

i has check this data and i find this :

```
tes = J.transpose()*J
```

and the result like this :

```
[[ 9.14761019e-05  9.41324993e-05 -8.79884397e-07]
 [ 9.41324993e-05  9.84768945e-05 -9.04538042e-07]
 [-8.79884397e-07 -9.04538042e-07  8.46387506e-09]]
```

I need to invert this matrix but this data is singular matrix. I have to try on matlab r2017b and running well.

I need to solve this problem on python.

Comment: Show the result you obtained from matlab

Comment: isn't the definition of a Singular Matrix, a square matrix that does not have a matrix inverse?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Yes it is. There is something called Psuedo Inverse for such matrices. I think he is referring to that

Comment: @WahyuHadinoto If you want a psuedo inverse use `linalg.pinv` from numpy

Comment: @WahyuHadinoto What function from matlab you used for this.?

Comment: @SreeramTP i have try to use that but i get this
 numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge

Comment: @WahyuHadinoto linalg.pinv works for the matrix you posted as you can see from my answer. There may be other cases in your problem where the generated matrices are such that psuedo inverse can'be determined. Also, make sure that your numpy and scipy are latest versions..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using [pseudo-inverse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) `numpy.linalg.pinv` instead? It's supposed to deal with these situations.

```
B = np.linalg.pinv(a)
```

But I would suggest to check that you really calculated correctly your matrix and a singular matrix is supposed to appear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the calculations you made are correct and it is what you wanted, then you can go for a psuedo inverse for the singular matrix that you are having.

It can be done in python like this..

```
mat = np.array([[ 9.14761019e-05,  9.41324993e-05, -8.79884397e-07],
 [ 9.41324993e-05,  9.84768945e-05, -9.04538042e-07],
 [-8.79884397e-07, -9.04538042e-07,  8.46387506e-09]])

p_inv = np.linalg.pinv(mat)

print(p_inv)

# output

array([[-1.00783988e+13,  5.50963966e+11, -9.88844703e+14],
       [ 5.50963966e+11, -3.01194390e+10,  5.40580308e+13],
       [-9.88844703e+14,  5.40580308e+13, -9.70207468e+16]])
```